# How to disable graphical shell?

Tags: linux, xorg, startup, upstart

I have a Linux system (Ubuntu) running in a VM, but now I want to disable the graphical shell. Where in the startup process are the graphical components launched? Is it some run-level dependent config? Which config files must I edit to stop it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can just disable `gdm` service:

```
sudo mv /etc/init/gdm.conf /etc/init/gdm.conf.off
```

Comment: If anyone is doing this in VirtualBox like me, it helps to know the keyboard shortcut for navigating to the virtual terminals, Host Key (e.g. right Ctrl) + e.g. F1 or whatever.

Answer (score 5):

You'd need to prevent `gdm` service from starting at boot. The problem is that Ubuntu uses the weird `upstart` thing... So there are no simple commands to disable booting of some service. You are left with either removing the gdm init script or editing it so that it doesn't run gdm. [See this thread for how this can be done](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1305659).

Answer (score 2):

Open the file `/etc/default/grub` and add to the variable `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` the string `text`.

Then, update GRUB's configuration file with

```
sudo update-grub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
systemctl disable gdm
```

Comment: there is no systemctl on Ubuntu (at least not on my 12.04 Ubuntu). On what version of Ubuntu would that work?

Comment: From `>16` for sure.

Answer (score 0):

On newer Ubuntu systems (e.g. version 12.04), there is no `gdm` as mentioned in some of the other answers. Instead it runs `lightdm`, you can configure that not to start with:

```
sudo -s -H
echo "manual" >> /etc/init/lightdm.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

With systems with Upstart at some point the following should have worked.

```
# service disable gdm
```